# How can I remove an inserted letter from a string?

Tags: c, string

I can't find out right solution. The problem is.

I've got a string `char availableLetters[ ]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";` and another one `char lettersGuessed[ ];`. The user gives me a letter that will be assigned into lettersGuessed string and after that deleted from availableLetters string.

It's part of code for Hangman game.

Answer (score 1):

```
char word[] = "abcdef";

int index = 2; //index of letter to be deleted 

memmove( & word[index], & word[index + 1], strlen(word) - 1);
//1 in the third argument is the number of characters you wish to remove
```

Before: `abcdef`

After: `abdef`

somehow if you're able to get the index of the letter that you want to remove, your work is done!

refer the link for more details on memmove function!

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memmove.htm

hope this helps! cheers!

Answer (score -1):

### Method-1

If you want `char var` from the character array `s`do simply this-

```
 void remove(char var,char *s)
    {
          int i;
          for(i=0;i<=strlen(s)-1 && s[i]!=var;i++)
               ;
          int k=i;
          for(i++;i<=strlen(s)-1;s[k++]=s[i++])
               ;
          s[k]=`\0';
    }
```

### Method-2

Simply take an array `int A[26]`. Initially all the elements are 1. Now when user gives an input make the corresponding entry in array zero.

```
for(int i=0;i<20;i++) A[i]=0;// initialization
char c;
scanf("%c",&c);
A[c-'a']=0;  // This character can't be used
//insert c in guessedstring;
```

That's it. You don't have to make a string for that.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void remCharacter( char * str, char character );

int main() {
    char myString[] = "any string";
    removeChar( myString, 'y' );
    printf( "Updated string: %s\n", myString );
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void remCharacter( char * str, char character ) {
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen( string ); i++ )

    if( string[i] == letter )
        strcpy( string + i, string + i + 1 );
}
```

just don't use `conio.h` and `getch()`

hope this will be helpful to you

Answer (score -1):

Here is demonstrated an approach how it can be done

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char * remove_letter( char *s, char c )
{
    char *p = strchr( s, c );

    if ( p != NULL && *p != '\0' )
    {
        do { *p = *( p + 1 ); } while ( *p++ );
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char availableLetters[ ] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    size_t n =  sizeof( availableLetters ) - 1;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        char c = availableLetters[rand() % ( n - i )];

        printf( "removed character : %c, result string: \"%s\"\n",
                c, remove_letter( availableLetters, c ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
removed character : y, result string: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxz"
removed character : s, result string: "abcdefghijklmnopqrtuvwxz"
removed character : j, result string: "abcdefghiklmnopqrtuvwxz"
removed character : b, result string: "acdefghiklmnopqrtuvwxz"
removed character : c, result string: "adefghiklmnopqrtuvwxz"
removed character : r, result string: "adefghiklmnopqtuvwxz"
removed character : w, result string: "adefghiklmnopqtuvxz"
removed character : f, result string: "adeghiklmnopqtuvxz"
removed character : o, result string: "adeghiklmnpqtuvxz"
removed character : g, result string: "adehiklmnpqtuvxz"
removed character : m, result string: "adehiklnpqtuvxz"
removed character : i, result string: "adehklnpqtuvxz"
removed character : d, result string: "aehklnpqtuvxz"
removed character : e, result string: "ahklnpqtuvxz"
removed character : l, result string: "ahknpqtuvxz"
removed character : x, result string: "ahknpqtuvz"
removed character : h, result string: "aknpqtuvz"
removed character : k, result string: "anpqtuvz"
removed character : u, result string: "anpqtvz"
removed character : v, result string: "anpqtz"
removed character : a, result string: "npqtz"
removed character : t, result string: "npqz"
removed character : p, result string: "nqz"
removed character : n, result string: "qz"
removed character : q, result string: "z"
removed character : z, result string: ""
```

It is funny to note that letter 'z' was the last one that was deleted.:) However if to run the program several times then it is not necessary that letter 'z' will be removed last.:)